# cropping out multiple regions around letters with python opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to process letters from an image with opencv and tesseract.  After processing my image I am left with this
[image]
which somewhat surprisingly to me tesseract cannot reliably OCR. However if I do a tight crop on an individual letter tesseract easily identifies it

[image: [2]]

Also the positions of the letters will not be the same in all images, so I need to be able to detect where to crop based on the contrast or some other metric.

I figure there must be a somewhat simple way to automate that cropping, turning my original image into 25 smaller images, which is actually more useful for my goal anyways. I am not experience with opencv though so I'm completely stuck.

Comment: Is it the problem of just cropping, or do you need to detect the placement of a latter somehow?

Comment: sorry @Hihikomori i should have been more clear will edit the main post aswell. 

The letters are not necessarily going to be in the same positions in all images, so detecting the placement is needed

Comment: just run findContours and filter by size. the only relevant contours are your letters. the only other contour is the big one encompassing the whole picture. see that you don't get white-to-black contours or filter them out.

Comment: Flood-fill with black color on any point in the background, this should give you a complete binary image where the characters are the only white blobs. If you need to further crop each character, just extract every white blob from the binary flood-filled image. Might as well implement an area filter, to filter out the small white noise.

Answer (score 0):

This code finds contours and crops the image by contour size.

```
img = cv2.imread("NkUK5.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours:
    x_r = np.amax(cnt[:,0,0])
    x_l = np.amin(cnt[:,0,0])
    y_b = np.amax(cnt[:, 0, 1])
    y_t = np.amin(cnt[:, 0, 1])

    show = img[y_t:y_b,x_l:x_r ]
    cv2.imshow("",show)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: I used your code after the floodfill idea someone else commented and it works decently, however im getting an issue where for example the letter D generates 3 cropped images

The[full D with border](https://i.imgur.com/PJ6pyoi.png),

[The D more tightly cropped](https://i.imgur.com/MXkrNHT.png)

and then [the inner portion of the D](https://i.imgur.com/fOfcR8C.png)

Comment: You can compare the centers of cropped regions to check whether it is the same letter or not.

Comment: Sorry for so many problems @Hihikomori, but after trying some additional processing ideas from other comments and getting [this image](https://i.imgur.com/GOn24jV.png) I get an error cv2.imshow("",show)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-8ely825f\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Comment: Check size of the image if it is not zero, and then call imshow.

Comment: @Calisto1988 if you are getting that exception after the crop operation, most likely the crop failed and produced an invalid sub image of size < 0.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this is the idea:

1. Read the input image and convert it to grayscale
2. Threshold it (Be sure to work with a binary image)
3. Flood-fill the background with black color
4. Perform an area filter (Ignore the little white blobs of pixels)
5. Look for outer contours and get their bounding boxes
6. Crop the image using the bounded boxes

This is the code:

```
# image path
path = 'C:/opencvImages/NkUK5.png'

# Reading an image in default mode:
image = cv2.imread(path)

# Copy of the input image:
inputCopy = image.copy()

# Convert RGB to grayscale:
grayscaleImage = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold image:
_, binaryImg = cv2.threshold(grayscaleImage, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Flood-fill background, seed at (0,0) and use black color:
cv2.floodFill(binaryImg, None, (0, 0), 0)

# Perform an area filter on the binary blobs:
componentsNumber, labeledImage, componentStats, componentCentroids = \
    cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(binaryImg, connectivity=4)

# Set the minimum pixels for the area filter:
minArea = 10

# Get the indices/labels of the remaining components based on the area stat
# (skip the background component at index 0)
remainingComponentLabels = [i for i in range(1, componentsNumber) if componentStats[i][4] >= minArea]

# Filter the labeled pixels based on the remaining labels,
# assign pixel intensity to 255 (uint8) for the remaining pixels
filteredImage = np.where(np.isin(labeledImage, remainingComponentLabels) == True, 255, 0).astype('uint8')

# Find the big contours/blobs on the filtered image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(filteredImage, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contours_poly = [None] * len(contours)
boundRect = []

# Alright, just look for the outer bounding boxes:
for i, c in enumerate(contours):

    if hierarchy[0][i][3] == -1:
        contours_poly[i] = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
        boundRect.append(cv2.boundingRect(contours_poly[i]))


# Draw the bounding boxes on the (copied) input image:
for i in range(len(boundRect)):
    color = (0, 255, 0)
    cv2.rectangle(inputCopy, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])), \
                  (int(boundRect[i][0] + boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1] + boundRect[i][3])), color, 2)

# Show the image
cv2.imshow('inputCopy', inputCopy)
```

This snippet gives you this final image, you can use the bounding boxes info to crop each character:

[image]

If the bounding boxes are too tight, you can set a height and width offset to get a less-restrictive crop. Now, my man, just so you know, this is my first answer in `Python`. I've used the `C++` implementation of OpenCV for years, but I'm just starting with the `Python` one. If you see something that offends your eyes in terms of good `Python` *uses and customs*, I'm sorry - I'll get better with time.

**Edit:**

Here's the bit that actually crops each character from the filtered image:

```
# Crop the characters:

for i in range(len(boundRect)):
    # Get the roi
    x, y, w, h = boundRect[i]

    # Crop the roi:
    croppedImg = filteredImage[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    cv2.imshow("Cropped Character: "+str(i), croppedImg)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And some of the cropped characters:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---